# Mercurial - see list of files that need to be manually merged?

Tags: mercurial

Is there a Mercurial command you can use after an `hg pull` to see a list of all files that will be need to be manually merged (ie: that have conflicts) when doing an `hg merge`?

Comment: I know it's been almost a year, but I just realized my answer wasn't quite right for your question. I have updated it to an answer that might be satisfactory.

Answer (score 40):

`hg resolve --list`

From the [documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html):

> Merges with unresolved conflicts are often the result of non-interactive merging using the internal:merge configuration setting, or a command-line merge tool like diff3. The resolve command is used to manage the files involved in a merge, after hg merge has been run, and before hg commit is run (i.e. the working directory must have two parents).

**Edit 5 January 2012:**

*(I received an up vote for this answer today so I revisited it. I discovered that I misunderstood the question.)*

The question is "I have performed a pull from a remote repository and **have not yet** performed a merge. Can I see what conflicts will be created upon performing the merge?"

My answer above is clearly wrong. After reading through the linked documentation, I do not think there is a built-in method for doing this. However, there is a way to do it without ruining your working source tree.

Let's assume you have cloned repository **A** from some remote source to repository **B** on your local system, i.e. `hg clone http://hg.example.com/A B`. After doing so, you make changes to your local repository, **B**, that involve at least one commit. In the meantime, changes have been made to repository **A** so that when you do a pull you get a message indicated new changesets have been added and heads have been created.

At this point, you can do `hg heads` to list the two changesets that will be involved in a merge. From this information, you can issue a status command to list the differences between the heads. Assuming the revision numbers in your repository **B**, according to the heads list, are "1" and "2", then you can do `hg status --rev 1:2` to see a list of the changes.

Of course, this doesn't really tell you if conflicts will occur when you do a merge. Since there isn't a command that will show you this, you will have to "preview" the merge by cloning to a new repository and doing the merge there. So, `hg clone B C && cd C && hg merge`. If you are satisfied with the result of this merge you can do `hg com -m 'Merging complete' && hg push && cd ../ && rm -rf C`.

It's a bit of a process, but it keeps your current source tree clean if the merge turns out to be a disaster. You might also find [this description](http://blogs.oracle.com/tor/entry/mercurial_tip_checking_in_regularly) of working with public repositories helpful.

Comment: I misread the question in the same way you did so your answer was still right for me.

Comment: If anyone is looking for a way to get the list of files names only (equivalent to `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U`) use `hg resolve --list --no-status "set:unresolved()"`.

Answer (score 6):

Unless I'm misreading it myself, the answers above don't seem to address the question that I think is being asked: I have two branches in my repository that I'd like to merge, and I want to know what conflicts will come up (e.g., before stepping through the conflict resolutions one-by-one.)

To do this, I would merge with the `:merge3` tool (which tries to merge automatically, but leaves conflicts unresolved) and then use `hg resolve --list` — or just look at the output of merge command — to see the conflicts.

```
hg merge <otherbranch> --tool :merge3
hg resolve -l
```

If you didn't actually want to merge in the end (if you just want to see what would conflict) you can run `hg update -C` afterwards to undo the merge.

If you do want to finish the merge, you can run `hg resolve <filepath>` for each file, or just `hg resolve --all` to step through all that remain with conflicts, before you `hg commit` the merge changeset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *--rev* option of *hg stat* with a pair of revisions to see what file differences exist between the two.  See below for a slightly verbose but detailed example:

First we start by making a new repository:

```
[gkeramidas /tmp]$ hg init foo
[gkeramidas /tmp]$ cd foo
```

Then add a single file called `foo.txt` to the new repository:

```
[gkeramidas /tmp/foo]$ echo foo > foo.txt
[gkeramidas /tmp/foo]$ hg commit -Am 'add foo'
adding foo.txt
[gkeramidas /tmp/foo]$ hg glog
@  0[tip]   b7ac7bd864b7   2011-01-30 18:11 -0800   gkeramidas
     add foo
```

Now add a second file, called `bar.txt` as revision 1:

```
[gkeramidas /tmp/foo]$ echo bar > bar.txt
[gkeramidas /tmp/foo]$ hg commit -Am 'add bar'
adding bar.txt
```

Go back to revision 0, and add a third file, on a different *head*.  This is done to simulate a *pull* from someone else who had cloned the same repository at its starting revision:

```
[gkeramidas /tmp/foo]$ hg up -C 0
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[gkeramidas /tmp/foo]$ echo koko > koko.txt
[gkeramidas /tmp/foo]$ hg commit -Am 'add koko'
adding koko.txt
created new head
[gkeramidas /tmp/foo]$ hg glog
@  2[tip]:0   e5d80abdcb06   2011-01-30 18:12 -0800   gkeramidas
|    add koko
|
| o  1   a2d0d0e66ce4   2011-01-30 18:12 -0800   gkeramidas
|/     add bar
|
o  0   b7ac7bd864b7   2011-01-30 18:11 -0800   gkeramidas
     add foo
```

Now you can use *hg stat* to see what file differences exist between any pair of revisions, e.g. the changes from rev 0 to rev 1 added 'bar.txt' to the file list:

```
[gkeramidas /tmp/foo]$ hg stat --rev 0:1
A bar.txt
```

The changes from rev 0 to rev2 added 'koko.txt' to the file list:

```
[gkeramidas /tmp/foo]$ hg stat --rev 0:2
A koko.txt
```

But more interestingly, the changes from rev 1 to rev 2 involve *two* file manifest changes. **(1)** 'koko.txt' was added in rev 2, and **(2)** 'bar.txt' exists in rev 1 but is missing from rev 2, so it shows as a 'removed' file:

```
[gkeramidas /tmp/foo]$ hg stat --rev 1:2
A koko.txt
R bar.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

I think `hg status` is what you are looking for.

You may want to read this chapter from Mercurial: The Definitive Guide

http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/mercurial-in-daily-use.html

Comment: hg status just shows "M" for all modified files, whether in conflict or not.However hg resolve --list works indeed.